# Is it possible to bind resize to body element?

Tags: jquery

```
$("body").bind("resize", function(){
  alert("document height changed");
});
```

Is it possible to bind resize to body element?
I wanted to use some script for adjusting the height of left side slider whenever the page height change so I am trying to use this because the page content area height will change based on dynamic content with out page refresh. on page load default code is working. but when I use tab menu items with different height the slider height not changing as per new height.

Comment: Try using on instead of bind

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you may detect that manually:

```js
function onElementHeightChange(elm, callback){
 var lastHeight = elm.clientHeight, newHeight;
 (function run(){
  newHeight = elm.clientHeight;
  if( lastHeight != newHeight )
   callback();
  lastHeight = newHeight;

        if( elm.onElementHeightChangeTimer )
          clearTimeout(elm.onElementHeightChangeTimer);

  elm.onElementHeightChangeTimer = setTimeout(run, 200);
 })();
}


onElementHeightChange(document.body, function(){
  alert('Body height changed');
});


$('button').on('click', function(){
    document.body.style.height = Math.floor((Math.random()*5000)+1) + 'px';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>detect document height changes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>change document height</button>
</body>
</html>
```